# Screenshot Chrome SSL error page via headless mode

Tags: google-chrome, puppeteer, headless

I'm trying to screenshot a Chrome SSL error page like the following using headless:
[image: Chrome SSL error]

This Puppeteer code hangs waiting for the screenshot(), but works for non-SSL error pages:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  const client = await page.target().createCDPSession()
  // await client.send('Security.setIgnoreCertificateErrors', {ignore: true}) 
  try {
    await page.goto('https://neverssl.com', {
    waitUntil: 'networkidle2',
    timeout: 1000});
    await page.screenshot({path: 'success.png'});
  }
  catch (ex) {
    console.log("ERROR", ex)
    await page.screenshot({path: 'error.png'});
  }
  await browser.close();
})();
```

I also tried setting `Security.setIgnoreCertificateErrors`, but that bypassed the error page completely.

Comment: Does the `ERROR` show up before it hangs?

Comment: Yes, it's hanging on `await page.screenshot({path: 'error.png'})`

Comment: [Interstitials are weird and do weird things](https://crbug.com/392354)

Answer (score 1):

**It looks like there is currently no way to capture a screenshot of interstitials in Chrome/Chromium.**

[Josh's link](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=392354) explains the reasons why in more depth, but the short answer is that SSL errors like my screenshot above are like a special overlay, and not actually part of the page. Trying to take a screenshot hangs because the actual page has not finished rendering.

Comment: So now (Josh's link)[https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=392354] is fixed, and the browser no longer hangs when capturing Chrome during errors... but all the driver will capture is a white box (nothing in it). Has anyone uncovered a solution to the original problem statement?